# Регулярные на php (preg_replace)

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Прописал так

```
   '/\[img\=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/img\]/is' => '<img src="$1" alt="$2" />'
```

эта регуляка действует на теги вида

```
[img=4_bh77jks0a.jpg]Картинка[/img]

[img=4_bh77jks0a.jpg][/img]
```

В итоге после ее запуска получаем

```
<img src="4_bh77jks0a.jpg" alt="Картинка" />

<img src="4_bh77jks0a.jpg" alt="" />
```

Мне так не нравится, хочу чтобы результат был таким

```
<img src="4_bh77jks0a.jpg" alt="Картинка" />

<img src="4_bh77jks0a.jpg" />
```

Как прописать регулярку для тега

```
[img=4_bh77jks0a.jpg][/img]
```

Чтобы она искала теги с пустым значением?

такой вариант не работает

```
'/\[img\=(.*?)\]\[\/img\]/is'
```

Comment: >такой вариант не работает

???

    $s = '[img=4_bh77jks0a.jpg][/img]';
    $s = preg_replace
    (  
        '/\[img\=(.*?)\]\[\/img\]/is', 
        '<img src="\1"/>', $s 
    );
    echo $s;  // вывод: <img src="4_bh77jks0a.jpg"/>

Comment: ни шиша он не работает, написал же

формирует мутатень вида

    <br />
    <img src="4_bh77jks0a.jpg]Картинка[/img]<br />
    <br />
    [img=4_bh77jks0a.jpg"/><br />
    <br />

Comment: в тексте могут встречаться теги 2-х видов, поэтому начинается путаница

вначале пытаюсь обработать все теги без слова Картинка а потом со словом

Comment: Смотрите в сторону preg_replace_callback, если за пару часов не разберетесь, то дам решение, не буду лишать Вас удовольствия самому найти ответ :)

Comment: @dfhsfhgf, тогда точку заменить на "не закрывающая скобка":

    /\[img\=([^\]]*?)\]\[\/img\]/

А за один проход - да, с callback всё просто :)

Comment: @dfhsfhgfj, т.е. вам не нравиться, что атрибут **alt** во втором случае пустой? Вы серьезно?! Просто я других отличий между тем, что выдает и тем, что вы хотите - не вижу.

Comment: Без альта вообще некузяво :) А если делать коллбэками (и если это не парсинг на лету каждый раз, а в статику), то я бы там и размер определял, проставляя width/height, и альт прописывал - если пустой, то размер в b/kb/mb.

Answer (score 1):

Два варианта- одной регуляркой и второй с функцией обратного вызова. Одним выражением делал исключительно для своего интереса (ну и Вам может интересно как все это выглядит одним выражением без каллбака). Используйте вариант с callback.

```
$text=<<< HEREDOC
[img=4_bh77jks0a.jpg]Картинка[/img]
[img=4_bh77jks0b.jpg][/img]
HEREDOC;
$RE1="/\[img=([^\]]*?)\](.*?)\[\/img\]/is";
$RE2="/\[img=([^\]]*?)\](.+?)?\[\/img\](?=.*(<img src=\")(\" )(\/>))(?(2)(?=.*(alt=\")(\" )))|#.*?$/is";
echo preg_replace_callback($RE1, "clb", $text)."\n\n";
echo preg_replace($RE2, "$3$1$4$6$2$7$5", $text."#<img src=\"\" />alt=\"\" ");
function clb($arr){
    return "<img src=\"$arr[1]\" ".($arr[2]?"alt=\"$arr[2]\" ":"")."/>";
}
```

Результат работы посмотрите здесь http://ideone.com/5kbz1K

Comment: Лучше через анонимную функцию, чтобы не засорять память идентификатором и придать "изящности".

    echo preg_replace_callback(
     $RE1, 
     function ($arr){
         return '<img src="' . $arr[1] . '" ' . ($arr[2] ? 'alt="' . $arr[2] . '" ' : '') . '/>';
     }, 
     $text
    ) . "\n\n";

Comment: @romeo, тут дело вкуса. Мне больше нравится в регулярных выражениях не мешать текстовые данные с кодом, при необходимости создания обратного вызова.

Comment: @ReinRaus оффтоп: Самара не спит - всё обмывает событие 31-го?:)

Comment: @romeo, ага- обмывали так, что даже спать побоялся лечь, чтобы работу не проспать :)